# Reading / Printing Varied # of Lines from Text File

Tags: java

I have a big text file (log file) which has approx 3000 line from where i need to fetch specific batch of lines. Here i can get the first line of batch (at what number it is we don't know) by using `".contains("Call Stack for Process :: [ NLNOTES:")` method but the end line varies according to logs generated.

```
    eg. 
    "START LINE OF BATCH (which has fixed `enter code here`format as below)" :

    <@@ ------ Notes Process Info -> Call Stack for Process :: [ NLNOTES:  xxxx] (Time 16:06:56) ------ @@> 

    ############################################################ 
    ### thread 1/19: [ NLNOTES:  xxxx:  xxxx] 
    ### xx=xxxxxxxx, xx=xxxxxxxx, xx=xxxxxxxx
    ### xxxxxxxx=xxxxxxxx, total xxxxxxxx=249856, used xxxxxxxx=30912
    ############################################################
     [ 1] 0x77a9a8fc ntdll.ZwWaitForSingleObject+12 (cb8,7530,0,5387f4)
    xxxx (0): SYM file xxxx.sym(74) for C:\xxxx\Notes\xxxx.dll ignored because it is xxxx
    ........
    .......

    "N NUMBER OF LINES"

    ############################################################ 
    ### thread 19/19: [ NLNOTES:  xxxx:  xxxx] 
    ### xx=xxxxxxxx, xx=xxxxxxxx, xx=xxxxxxxx
    ### xxxxxxxx=xxxxxxxx, total xxxxxxxx=249856, used xxxxxxxx=30912
    ############################################################

    "N NUMBER OF LINES"

    .........WHITE SPACE..........."END LINE OF BATCH"

    "START OF ANOTHER BATCH"
    <@@ ------ Notes Process Info -> Load Modules for Process :: [ntaskldr:  xxxx] (Time 16:06:59) ------ @@>
   -------------------------------------------------------
    public class NLNOTES_Reader {

         public String[] readLines(String NLfile) throws IOException 
            {
                FileReader nlr = new FileReader(NLfile);    
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(nlr);
                List<String> nllines = new ArrayList<String>();
                String line = null;

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) 
                {
                    if ( line.trim().length() == 0) {
                        continue;  // Skip blank lines
                      }
                    nllines.add(line);
                }

                bufferedReader.close();


                return nllines.toArray(new String[nllines.size()]);
            }   
    }
    -------------------------------------------------
    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            NLNOTES_Reader nl = new NLNOTES_Reader();
            String NLfile = "src/data.txt"; 
            try
            {   
                String[] lines = nl.readLines(NLfile);        
                for (String line : lines) 
                {
                        if (line.contains("Call Stack for Process :: [ NLNOTES:")) {

                            System.out.println(line.substring(33,line.length()-11));
                         }
                    System.out.println((line));
                }
            }
            catch(IOException ie)
            {
                // Print out the exception that occurred
               System.out.println("Unable to create "+NLfile+": "+ie.getMessage());   
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Does the first line of a batch _always_ start with`"<@@"?  The example seems to suggest that, but is it, in fact, true?

Comment: What's a general # of lines that should be returned from this behaviour?  Ballpark count.

Comment: @KevinAnderson yes it always starts with "<@@"

Comment: @J.Murray yes it should return #

Comment: OK, batches always start with `"<@@"`; does that also mean that _every_ line that begins with `"<@@"` starts a new batch?

Comment: Well there's your solution, then.  Read through the log file line by line. Do nothing more until you see a line `"Call Stack for Process :: [ NLNOTES:"`; at that point, start  printing out the lines or adding them into a list or whatever; when you eventually see a line that starts with "`<@@`" (or you reach the end of the log file), you're done!

Comment: @KevinAnderson does that also mean that every line that begins with "<@@" : No

Comment: @KevinAnderson I ll try and let you know ..thank you Kevin